# Activated in baseclass not triggered?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have something like this :

```
public class WinformBase : Winform
{
     public WinformBase (){
         this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.MyTest1_Activated);
     }
     private void MyTest1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        MyController.TopFormActivated(this);
     }
}

public class MyForm : WinformBase
{
      public MyForm (){
         this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.MyTest2_Activated);

      }
      private void MyTest2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        MyController.TopFormActivated(this);
      }
}
```

The problem is that the event is only triggered in MyForm and not in the Winform base?
Why is that so, and how can I have the event triggered in `WinformBase` too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my solution to the problem :

```
public class WinformBase : Winform
{
     public WinformBase (){
     }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);
        Controller.MyMethod();
    }

}

public class MyForm : WinformBase
{
      public MyForm (){
      }
}
```